# Trace function and inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, inner-products, matrix-equations

Let $F$ be a  field. Consider the a mapping on the algebra of all linear transformations on $F^n$ that are triangularizable  as follows:
$$(T,A)=trace(TA).$$ Then this is an inner product and non-singular.

Why?

( In fact, Trace function is $\sum a_{i}\lambda_{i}$, where $\lambda_i$'s are eigenvalues of $TA$ and $a_i$'s are algebriac multiplicities of $\lambda_i$'s.)
 Also, the eigenvalues are in $F$.

Comment: What is $A$? Is $T$ just any transformation?

Comment: Yes. T , A are in $M_{n}(F)$.

Comment: Trace function is $\sum a_{i}\lambda_{i}$, where $\lamda_i$'s are eigenvalues of $TA$ and $a_i$'s are algebriac multiplicities of $\lambda_i$'s.

Comment: Well, trace is a little more standard. However, "the space of all linear transformations" (I'm guessing) means maps $F^n \to F^n$. Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Note that trace is bi-linear, so it certainly gives a multilinear function $F^n \times F^n \to F$.

Perhaps the "best" thing about the trace function is that $tr(AB)=tr(BA)$ which can be proven from the explicit construction of trace, since the diagonals of such matrices do not change. This gives the second requirement for an inner product (symmetry.)

What is left to show: if $tr(A^2)=0$, then $A=0$, but only matrices of the form $XY-YX$ have trace zero.

**Edit:** using your definition of trace and the additional assumption, what are the eigenvalues for $A^2$? can their sum ever be zero?

Comment: Thanks so much. I edit this, that T and A are triangularizable

Comment: Now, why is this mapping invertible?